# Can enough motors generate the current to turn a separate one?

Tags: power-supply, power, current

I'm trying to keep a battery on an aircraft charged, but an alternator won't do the job. Can a lot of DC motors keep a battery in a state of sufficient charge to run two others? And, even more importantly, can a DC motor generate the same level of current and voltage output as is required for an input on that motor? For example, can a motor with a 12V 2A input create 12V 2A of output?

Comment: Power in = Power out, minus losses. So figure on not getting anything for free.

Comment: This question sounds crazy: (1) DIY electrics and aircraft. (2) "_An alternator won't do the job._" Alternators are designed to generate. Motors aren't. (3) Use a motor to drive a motor and charge a battery? Why not drive the second motor directly?

Comment: Thanks. I figured that they wouldn't be able to do everything. I would use wind to turn the generating motors.

Comment: Have you considered finding out why the alternator can't keep the battery charged? Alternator defective, or batteries too old?

Comment: An alternator will only give a fraction of the charge that is needed to turn the motor wit the power necessary.I am considering an aircraft that is completely electrical. I need a battery so that I have a buffer to vary motor speed and therefore throttle.

Comment: @nicholas, are you trying to capture the force from the airstream of a flying aircraft to generate power so that it can keep flying?  If so that won't work.  If you're trying to generate power for some other reason, what is that reason?

Comment: @BowlOfRed, as long as he continuously loses altitude, he should be okay.

Comment: @Nicholas: It seems that you are proposing to have one propeller driving the plane forward and another driving the generator and acting as a brake. Try this with an electric car before you take to the air. A couple of 3 V DC toy motors and propellers should be adequate to test your idea.

Comment: @Transistor I'm actually trying to use motors as the generators, not to turn the generators, though your idea seems interesting. Sounds like it wouldn't generate forever, though.

Comment: The idea is similar to the Makani windkites. Here's the link :  https://www.google.com/makani/

Comment: @Nicholas, everyone is trying to tell you that the idea will not work at all. It is the same as trying to create a car which will run are Dynamo's connected to the wheels.

Comment: You can definitely generate power by trailing an impeller-driven generator in the slipstream of the aircraft. Commercial aircraft can do this in certain emergency conditions. The available energy will be less than the energy required to fly the aircraft on a level path (unless you are in lift, from a slope, or cumulus cloud or pocket of hot rising air). Makani kites are kites. Is your aircraft also a kite? The string to ground changes everything, because it supplies forward force to keep the kite flying (instead of a propeller).

Comment: @mkeith Thanks. I will keep that in mind. I might use motors just to generate power for the systems.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for has been known for a long time - it's called a perpetual motion machine.

If it were possible, you could do the following:

1) Take a 12 volt, 2 amp power source, and connect it to your desired motor and generator. Just as a start, let's say that the generator will put out 12 volts at 4 amps.

2) Connect the generator to 2 motors.

3) Connect the 2 motors to 2 generators each, or 4 generators.

4) Continue the process until you have megawatts of power being generated (16 generations) or gigawatts (another 20 or so after that).

5) At some point connect one of the generators back to the original motor and turn off the power supply.

Do you see the problem?

If you use a motor/generator with a gain of 1.5 (12 volts and 3 amps) it takes more layers to get to a specific power, but the principle remains the same. Any motor/generator which puts out more power than is put in is impossible under the current understanding of how the universe works. So your electric airplane has the energy stored in the battery at takeoff. And no more.

Comment: If you glue a big magnet to Isaac Newton (spinning in his grave) and get some wire and then...

Comment: Noether's theorem gives that energy is conserved only when the results of experiments don't change with time. So, just find a way to break physics.

Answer (score 0):

You can get power by rotating the shaft of an ordinary brushed DC motor.  I did that experiment many times as a kid, and was able to power a small light bulb.  When I did it I had to turn the motor very fast to get any significant power.  I usually used a set of gears to increase the rotation speed 50x what I was cranking at with my hand.

The amount of power you get out will always be less than what you put in.  How much less depends on the specific motor and circuits attached to it.  But don't expect the efficiency to be very high.

You may be able connect two identical motors and have one turn the other.  But you would most likely have to turn the first one very fast to only get a little motion out of the second one, mainly because of the poor efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Others mentioned the paradox of 'perpetual motion'/'free energy' you brought up (you can't generate more power from the battery than you are using).

I wanted to mention another theme you mentioned, which is turning the turbines with wind.  This will be difficult since the wind must be doing the work (as opposed to the original motor which is now dragging these "generators" through the wind) or else there will not be any positive net power generated.  I am not sure if this is even possible at all (but I am certain it won't generate enough power to cover the cost of flying). I can't say for sure about the details though since I am an electrical engineer and don't know much about airplanes.

Just assuming you could somehow harvest the wind energy (maybe by going up into a jetwind and just idling while it spun your "generators"), it is now going to take a lot more battery power to drive the airplane (since it weighs more for each motor -- the heaviest part most likely). So now you need even more battery power for the extra weight.

What about solar panels as the wings or a more efficient alternator, making all of the plane as light as possible?  Still, even the best alternator will not get back the same electricity as you put in.